# Bug in viewcounter?

Tags: support, migration

The second question from above. There should be something wrong?

Or why is this?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that nobody viewed it yet.

It was posted 1m ago, so this perfectly possible.

Comment: But 23 votes and 13 answers without viewing it?

Comment: Because it has been migrated from another site, and those votes has been made on the other site.